# Notepad ++ not responding

Tags: notepad++

This all started because I tried to open a very large file by right clicking on a text file and then selecting "edit with notepad++". Since then I have removed and reinstalled. I have followed the steps in (**https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/21755/notepad-not-responding/2**) but when I put the items listed in steps 2 and 3.. it tells me that they are not valid commands. At the moment, If I open it it says, "not responding" and stays that way indefinitely. Any ideas as to get this operational?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Uninstalling probably is not clearing out the program's entry in AppData. Go to C:\Users[YourUser]\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++ and you might be okay with just removing the session.txt file (this appears to be the file that tells NotePad++ which files you had open). If that doesn't work delete everything here then try on a fresh install.

Edit: Also your commands are probably not recognized as valid because notepad++ is not in your PATH variable. Try opening a command prompt in the same folder as notepad++'s exe THEN running them from there

Comment: Had probably about 50x 500MB-1GB files open and was wondering why notepad took multiple minutes to start .. This is the solution. Be aware that any edits you did, probably won't be recoverable.